# Install CentOS 6 entirely from a script?

Tags: linux, installation, centos

After having to manually install CentOS 6 on a few servers, with the same configuration (Software RAID 1, partition size, etc.) is there a way to prepare this to run entirely from a script? Or a method to create a bootable DVD-ROM of this that does the entire installation automatically not requiring any prompts to be answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Kickstart](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-whatis.html) for scripted installation

> Many system administrators would prefer to use an automated installation method to install Red Hat Enterprise Linux on their machines. To answer this need, Red Hat created the kickstart installation method. Using kickstart, a system administrator can create a single file containing the answers to all the questions that would normally be asked during a typical installation.
>
> Kickstart files can be kept on a single server system and read by individual computers during the installation. This installation method can support the use of a single kickstart file to install Red Hat Enterprise Linux on multiple machines, making it ideal for network and system administrators.
>
> Kickstart provides a way for users to automate a Red Hat Enterprise Linux installation.

<sub>(Kickstart in CentOS should be same as in RedHat Enterprise Linux minus branding etc)</sub>

Comment: and you can do a pxe boot to do a completely automated install that picks the image from network and kickstart. You would need a tftp and dhcp server to do this.